# Laravel eloquent get data on multiple tables grouped by hours

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

This is my expected output:

```
{
{
    "visits": 10,
    "clicks": 2,
    "sales": 0,
    "hour": 15
}

{
    "visits": 24
    "clicks": 12,
    "sales": 1,
    "hour": 15
}
}
```

...

For now i can get the results with 3 queries :

```
$user->$visits
            ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as `visits`'),DB::raw('HOUR(created_at) hour'))
            ->groupby('hour')
            ->orderBy('hour')
            ->get();

$user->$clicks
            ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as `clicks`'),DB::raw('HOUR(created_at) hour'))
            ->groupby('hour')
            ->orderBy('hour')
            ->get();

$user->$sales
            ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as `sales`'),DB::raw('HOUR(created_at) hour'))
            ->groupby('hour')
            ->orderBy('hour')
           ->get()
```

Then merge this 3 collections.

How can i get the expected output in one query ? i'm pretty sure this is the job of mysql and does not need to be treated by php.

Comment: any particular reason why you want to do that using multiple queries? how are the relations between this models? does the thing even works? seems a bit funny to me

Comment: @g3ek1337 The reason why i'm doing multiple queries is because i don't know how to do it in one. That's why i ask help here. Yes this thing work but it's not elegant :) I'm looking for a better way.